# How to select the "whole word" by office.js

Tags: office-js, cpu-word, word-addins

Below is the code that I want to select text from a Word document by office.js in React. The selected words can be one words or several word. The code below can do the selection, but cannot automatically select the "whole word". It depends on where the mouse stopped. For example, if I only selected "For examp", my selection is "For examp", but I want "For example". How do I do that? Thanks!

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (asyncResult){
if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
  console.log("Action failed. Error: " + asyncResult.error.message);
} else {
  console.log("selected", asyncResult.value);

}
```

});

Comment: You should use the Word-specific APIs. Try making an array of ranges that includes a range for each whole word. Then iterate the array with `range.compareRangeLocation()` for the selected range. If you find a range that overlaps with the selected range, use `range.expandTo()` to expand the selected range to include the range of the whole word.

Comment: @RickKirkham Hi Rick, your idea sounds very good. However the document is in Typescript which I am not familiar with. Can you help to write some JS/React snippet? Where I can get all the samples? I am new to Office.JS. It is hard to find helpful training videos. Thank you so much!

Comment: What document is in Typescript? Use [Script Lab](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/overview/explore-with-script-lab) to explore the Word Office.js APIs. And see [Word JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview).